# What is happening between PreRender and Unload

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, umbraco6

I have an ASP.NET Webforms master page which is taking 3.5 minutes to render, and I can't figure out why.

I added logging, and it goes through Load and PreRender super fast, but after that, takes 3.5 minutes to get to Unload.

The page being rendered is pretty small, about 80k, and the viewstate is about 10k (guessing).

Comment: Are you logging how long any of [the other life cycle events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#lifecycle_events) take to execute?  To answer your question, these three events occur during that period: PreRenderComplete, SaveStateComplete, and Render.

Comment: @jadarnel27 No.  I'm logging on a master page, so just where the problem is happening.  I don't think a master page has access to events between PreRender and Unload

Comment: The events for your content page run before your MasterPage unloads.  That is probably where the problem is occurring.  You should take a look at what's happening there.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  In my case, Umbraco was responsible for generating the 'Page' as all I had was a MasterPage containing controls.  One of these controls had a datasource which was making web requests for each row it got back from the database.  These requests were failing silently and timing out.